# How to save ID2D1Bitmap to Image file?

Tags: c++, winapi, video, ms-media-foundation

I need to save all the frames in a video, I have managed to get them all but I am unable to save ID2D1Bitmap to image file.

Please could any one help me that how can I save ID2D1Bitmap to image file ?

Thanks,
SKAR

Comment: This question was already asked, although the answer was not accepted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725453/how-to-save-bmp-file-from-id2d1bitmap

Comment: Thanks @JonathanPotter, but I need a C++ sample.